# ¿Por qué se dice "fila india" para expresar "en fila de a uno"? ¿Cuándo se originó la expresión?

Tags: expresiones

Acabo de oír la expresión *[en fila india](https://dle.rae.es/?id=HtQM65L#9DxlT1Q)* (añadida al DLE en 1936) y me ha llamado la atención. Estoy leyendo en [el blog de Alfred López](https://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/por-que-se-dice-ir-en-fila-india/) lo siguiente:

> La expresión proviene de la época en la que los indígenas poblaban gran parte de los territorios aún sin colonizar. Cuando estos se trasladaban a pie de un lugar a otro, lo hacían avanzando uno detrás de otro debido a que en la gran mayoría de lugares aún no existían los caminos o senderos y muchas veces se abrían por el paso de aquellos exploradores.

El texto tiene sentido, aunque siempre me choca la falta de fuentes de dicho blog. Así pues, ¿qué textos existen para dar credibilidad a dicho origen? ¿Existe alguna otra explicación para el origen de la expresión? ¿Desde cuándo se usa?

De momento el texto más antiguo que he encontrado es este:

> *Vinieron entonces los demas salvages á mi choza uno por uno, lo que se llama fila india, danzando y cantando canciones de guerra; [...].*
>
> Varios autores, "El viagero universal, ó noticia del mundo antiguo y nuevo. Tomo XXV", 1799 (España).

Comment: If it is of any interest we use the same phrase and its etymology in English is discussed https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30116/why-is-it-called-an-indian-file here with some interesting pictures.

Comment: @mdewey I had no idea this expression existed in English (and seemingly in French and Italian).

Comment: @mdewey [asked in English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/499961/280768) about the first uses of the English expression.

Comment: But not apparently in German where it is goose march or duck march. Which does make sense if you have ever seen goslings or ducklings following the adult.

Answer (score 2):

Por dejarlo aquí reflejado, parece que la expresión se originó como un calco del inglés *Indian file*. Mientras que los textos en español casi llegando el siglo XIX usaban la expresión como algo desconocido ("lo que llaman fila india"), existen textos en inglés de mediados del siglo XVIII que la usan sin más explicaciones, como atestigua [esta respuesta](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/499986/280768) del sitio de inglés:

> The earliest text I can find using the expression dates to 1758, in
>   "Extract of a Letter from Albany, August 14, 1758" in the August 21,
>   1758 edition of the New-York Gazette, or the Weekly Post-Boy, as
>   accessed through the database *America's Historical Newspapers*:
>
> > Our people were discovered by some of the Provincials firing at Pigeons : Rogers's Party was then in an **Indian File**, which took up
> >     a long while before the Rear came up. (p. 3)
>
> [...]
>
> This 1758 occurrence of "Indian File" is interesting for a number of
>   reasons. The military action of the "Indian File" is one initiated by
>   a British officer; the letter writer doesn't need to explain the
>   action in detail but does provide a contextual clue for understanding
>   it ("which took up a long while"); this is occurring during a war (The
>   French and Indian War [1754-1763], often treated as the American
>   theater of the Seven Years' War) where both French Canadian and
>   British American forces served alongside indigenous forces from
>   several tribes and adapted many of their tactics.
>
> For these reasons, even if the letter writer didn't create the term,
>   the term most likely came out of the French and Indian War.

Los dos últimos párrafos sitúan la creación de la expresión en algún momento de la [guerra franco-india](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guerra_franco-india), entre 1754 y 1763. [Otra respuesta](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/30134/280768) además ilustra la expresión con esta imagen:

[image: Indian file]

Por el texto mencionado en la pregunta, la expresión debió de pasar al español a través de viajeros que exploraron las zonas de habla inglesa en las que esta expresión se había hecho ya común, adaptándola e introduciéndola en nuestro idioma.